# SQL query to get Most Frequently purchased and Most Recently purchased quantity for a customer-product pair

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table `Customer_Order_Data` with these columns:

1. customer_id
2. order_id
3. product_id
4. quantity
5. order_date

For all the dataset available I want to find out the most frequently purchased quantity and most recently purchased quantity for a customer-product pair.

Let's say I have the following data -

| Order_id | Customer_id | product_id | Quantity | order_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | ABCD | B019 | 7 | 2020-01-01 |
| 00002 | ABCD | B019 | 6 | 2020-05-23 |
| 00003 | EFGH | B018 | 8 | 2020-01-12 |
| 00004 | ABCD | B019 | 7 | 2020-02-14 |
| 00005 | EFGH | B018 | 6 | 2020-04-18 |
| 00006 | ABCD | B019 | 7 | 2020-04-19 |
| 00007 | EFGH | B018 | 8 | 2020-03-12 |

I want to group the rows based on customer_id.

Result expected -

| Customer_id | product_id | Most frequently Purachsed | Most Recently Purchased |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD | B019 | 7 | 6 |
| EFGH | B018 | 8 | 6 |

I am unable to add dummy columns to vend out this type of view.

PostgreSQL 8.0.26

Comment: Please edit your question and tag the database that you are using and what you have tried so far.?

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.0.26 - @Popeye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing the statistical *mode* - and a top-1-per-group problem. A few databases have a built-in aggregate function to compute it, but a generic approach is:

```
select * 
from (
    select customer_id, product_id, quantity, count(*) as cnt,
        rank() over(partition by customer_id, product_id order by count(*) desc) rn1,
        max(case when rn = 1 then quantity end) as most_recently_purchased
    from (
        select t.*,
            row_number() over(partition by customer_id, product_id order by order_date desc) rn
        from mytable t
    ) t
    group by customer_id, product_id, quantity
) t
where rn1 = 1
```